# How to get data from Firebase into Ionic 3-- Child data

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I want to grab data from firebase and then put all gather data into a for loop for ionic content to generate buttons.

my data is

[image: My Database]

I want to be able to grab all the phones that are currently in the database and create buttons  --Don't remember the right code as typing this.

so being able to grab all available phones in Ionic Framework 3.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, You saved all children in root.

so retrive all data,

```
let user_data= [];

firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) => {
    let result = snapshot.value();
    for(let k in result){ //"k" provides key Id of each object
     user_data.push({
       id : k,
       name : result[k].name,
       phone : result[k].phone,
     });
    }
});
```

To show data on the front view, you can listed all phones like this way

```
<div *ngFor="let phone of user_data" >
  {{phone.phone}}
</div>
```

hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```js
data = [];
constructor(af: AngularFireDatabase...) {
    this.data = [];
}


this.af.object('/FirebaseData/')
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe(data => {
        let arr = Object.keys(data);
        this.data = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            const object2 = Object.assign({ Key: arr[i] }, data[arr[i]]);
            this.data.push(object2);
        }
```